# Returning a value from a method in python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm coming from perl to python, and this question seems to be ungoogleable for  the clutter of unrelated examples.

I'm trying to make a fast lookup index for a variable length list of objects. The objects can be returned by name or number. The methods byname and bynum are throwing a syntax error at "return"

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

```
class BookSumIndex():

        bookptr = 0
        BookSum = []; # object container
        ByName = {}   # named referent to objects 
        ByNum = {}    # numerical referent to objects

        def addbook(self,thisbook,bookname,booknum):
                self.BookSum.insert(self.bookptr,BookSumObject())
                namepair = {bookname:self.bookptr}
                numpair = {booknum:self.bookptr}
                self.ByName.update(namepair)
                self.ByNum.update(numpair)
                self.bookptr += 1

        def byname(self,bookname):
                bnam = self.ByName.get(bookname)
                if type(bnam) != "NoneType":
                        thisbook = self.BookSum.get[int(bnam)]
                        return thisbook

        def bynum(self,booknum):
                bnum = self.ByNum.booknum
                if type(bnum) != "NoneType":
                        thisbook = self.BookSum[self.ByNum.get[int(bnum)]
                        return thisbook
```

Comment: Missing a closing bracket at `self.BookSum[self.ByNum.get[int(bnum)]`. Let this be a lesson to not do too much in a single line of code.

Comment: `thisbook = self.BookSum[self.ByNum.get[int(bnum)]` is missing a closing `]`. Always check the previous line when you get errors like this.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - `get` is a method!  The wrong type of brackets are being used.

Comment: Can you show `BookSumObject`?  Are you trying to implement inside-out objects in python?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Regarding inside-out objects, I guess I am. I never heard that before, but I've been doing it for a long time in perl. Probably learned it from somebody elses code. Hope it isn't a considered a mortal sin in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace of this book in the bynum method.

```
thisbook = self.BookSum[self.ByNum.get[int(bnum)]
```

should be:

```
thisbook = self.BookSum[self.ByNum.get[int(bnum)]]
```

I also suggest you use the comparison:

```
bnum is not None
```

instead of:

```
type(bnum) == "NoneType"
```

I'm not sure why you are getting a syntax error but since a method not returning a value would allocate a None to the variable you may as well return a None to see if the IDE doesn't flag the methods any longer.  E.g:

```
def bynum(self,booknum):
    bnum = self.ByNum.booknum
    if bnum is not None:
        thisbook = self.BookSum[self.ByNum.get[int(bnum)]
        return thisbook
    else:
        return None
```

Also just in case check the indentation of this book and return like I have above.

Comment: `get` is a method, not a dictionary or a list.